# Reasoning behind 'sort' core util's key (-k) syntax

Tags: linux, bash, shell

When using the `sort` function in a shell, it seems the preferred syntax for the `-k` option when sorting via only one field is, for example, `-k5n,5`. What's the advantage of the `,5` in this case? `-k5n` works the same, or at least seems to for me.

**Refs:**

1. [The man page seems to prefer this but also suggests it is optional](http://ss64.com/bash/sort.html)
2. [This answer seems to prefer this syntax too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3193769/1898563)

Comment: I had some problems where `-k 3g` did not work. Only `-k 3g,3` did the trick.

Comment: @RedX and do you know why?

Comment: Never understood the problem, but without the trailing `,5` I sometimes got wrong (unexpected) results. Using the 'comma syntax' since then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your data has `N` fields. `-k5n` is equivalent to `-k5,Nn`, meaning the data will be sorted using fields 5 through `N` as the key. This may not be desirable, for instance if you want a stable sort that doesn't modify the relative order of records in the input with equal values for the 5th field. Using `-k5,5n` makes it explicit that you want to sort on the 5th field alone.

Comment: Can you provide a test case for this? I have been trying it out and i have not found out what difference it makes... It seems to be random. I have been using following test varable: `k="    one two 1 7 one two\n
    one two 2 5 one two\n
    one two 1 6 one two\n
    one two 3 3 one two\n
    one two 4 1 one two\n
    one two 3 2 one two\n
    one two 2 4 one two\n"`. it alwys sorts also the second column independently of `-k3,3` or not.

Comment: Isn't `-k5` already pretty explicit that you only want to sort by one field though? There's nothing else this could potentially mean, is there? Sorting a range of adjacent fields via a range seems like it would be much more uncommon than using one or multiple `-kN` clauses. I feel as if the syntax of the more common cases is being dictated by an edge case, which seems unreasonable. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Michael It might be nice if `-k5` were equivalent to `-k5,5` instead of `-k5,N`, but it just isn't.

Comment: @chepner I think that's what I was trying to get at with my question - why it *wasn't* implemented like that. It seems, based on this question at least, that the present implementation has a tendency to confuse people.

Comment: Unless the original developer of `sort` shows up, all you're going to get is opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The second key specifies the stop position, which defaults to the end of the line.

So you could omit it and often it would make no practical difference,  but it could be significant if, for example, you used the `-u` option to only output lines with unique key matches.

Also, you can specify multiple key parts with multiple `-k` options, so in that case you need to specify the end point of the key part.

There are probably other cases where it matters.