# how can i sort the content of a file by date?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal

i have a file with the next content :

```
linux-4.4.1.tar.gz      31-Jan-2016 19:34  127M
linux-4.4.2.tar.gz      17-Feb-2016 20:35  127M
linux-4.4.3.tar.gz      25-Feb-2016 20:13  127M
linux-4.4.4.tar.gz      03-Mar-2016 23:16  127M
linux-4.4.5.tar.gz      09-Mar-2016 23:44  127M
linux-4.4.6.tar.gz      16-Mar-2016 16:28  127M
linux-4.4.7.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:13  127M
linux-4.4.8.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  127M
linux-4.4.tar.gz        10-Jan-2016 23:12  127M
linux-4.5.1.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:08  128M
linux-4.5.2.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  128M
linux-4.5.tar.gz        14-Mar-2016 04:38  128M
```

and i would like to get this content filtered by their dates , but im not sure how can i do that, so far i have only the following code to convert the dates for a comparation but im not sure how to use it in bash code in order to filter the file:

```
date -d 20-Apr-2016 +"%Y%m%d"
```

Comment: did you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193720/unix-sorting-with-primary-and-secondary-keys

Comment: Not sure how you generate your file. If its with 'ls', there are options to sort it by date - see 'man ls'. Btw. filtering reduces lines, sorting sorts. Your question sounds like sort instead of filter...

Answer (score 2):

[Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform):

```
while read -r line; do
  d=$(date -d "${line:24:11}" +"%Y%m%d")
  echo "$d $line"
done < file | sort -k1,1n | cut -d " " -f 2-
```

Output:

```
linux-4.4.tar.gz        10-Jan-2016 23:12  127M
linux-4.4.1.tar.gz      31-Jan-2016 19:34  127M
linux-4.4.2.tar.gz      17-Feb-2016 20:35  127M
linux-4.4.3.tar.gz      25-Feb-2016 20:13  127M
linux-4.4.4.tar.gz      03-Mar-2016 23:16  127M
linux-4.4.5.tar.gz      09-Mar-2016 23:44  127M
linux-4.5.tar.gz        14-Mar-2016 04:38  128M
linux-4.4.6.tar.gz      16-Mar-2016 16:28  127M
linux-4.4.7.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:13  127M
linux-4.5.1.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:08  128M
linux-4.4.8.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  127M
linux-4.5.2.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  128M
```

Comment: Nice one. But `24:11` assumption is a bit dangerous, Isn't it

Comment: okay, to make it more robust: `[[ $line =~ [^" "]*" "*([^" "]*)" "[^" "]*" "[^" "]* ]]; d=$(date -d "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" +"%Y%m%d")`. I assume he used no tabs.

Answer (score 2):

If open to `perl` then Schwartzian transform is best implemented in it. This uses a core module so no need to install one from CPAN.

```
perl -MTime::Piece -lane'
    push @rows, [ $_,  join (" ", $F[1], $F[2]) ];
}{
    print for
      map  { $_->[0] }
      sort {
          Time::Piece->strptime($a->[1], "%d-%b-%Y %R") <=>
          Time::Piece->strptime($b->[1], "%d-%b-%Y %R")
      }
      map  { [ $_->[0], $_->[1] ] } @rows;
' file
linux-4.4.tar.gz        10-Jan-2016 23:12  127M
linux-4.4.1.tar.gz      31-Jan-2016 19:34  127M
linux-4.4.2.tar.gz      17-Feb-2016 20:35  127M
linux-4.4.3.tar.gz      25-Feb-2016 20:13  127M
linux-4.4.4.tar.gz      03-Mar-2016 23:16  127M
linux-4.4.5.tar.gz      09-Mar-2016 23:44  127M
linux-4.5.tar.gz        14-Mar-2016 04:38  128M
linux-4.4.6.tar.gz      16-Mar-2016 16:28  127M
linux-4.5.1.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:08  128M
linux-4.4.7.tar.gz      12-Apr-2016 16:13  127M
linux-4.4.8.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  127M
linux-4.5.2.tar.gz      20-Apr-2016 07:00  128M
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using GNU AWK, then a script like this would work:

**conv_date.awk**

```
BEGIN   { # sort array numerically
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
        # prepare a mapping month name to month-number:
        split("JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC", tmp," ")
        for( ind in tmp ) { monthMap [ tmp[ ind ] ] = ind }
      }

      { split( $2, dt, /[-]/)
        ts = mktime( dt[3] " " monthMap[ toupper( dt[2]) ] " " dt[1] " 0 0 0" )
        if (ts in lines) lines[ts] = lines[ts] "\n" $0
        else lines[ts] = $0
      }

END   { # output in chronological order
        for( l in lines ) print lines[ l ]
      }
```

Use it like this: `awk -f conv_date.awk your_file`

Comment: What happens when you have two files with same date and timestamp?

Comment: @jaypalsingh Thanks for the hint, I added a check for that case.

Answer (score 0):

Save the script

```
#!/bin/bash

reorder()
{
awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s\n",$2,$3,$1,$4}' $1 \
| sort -t'-' -k2 -M \
| awk '{printf "%s %s %s %s\n",$3,$1,$2,$4}' #You can omit this pipe
}

reorder $1
```

as sortcontent.sh and run it like

```
./sortcontent.sh your_file_name
```